# Installshield error: "the checksum of vstor40_x86.exe is incorrect"

Tags: vsto, md5, installshield, checksum, prerequisites

Whilst trying to download the *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime*,  redistributable from *inside InstallShield* you always get `the checksum of vstor40_x86.exe is incorrect`.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Edit "Microsoft VSTO 2010 Runtime.prq" from the folder folder:
Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012Spring\SetupPrerequisites

Modify the  properties:
CheckSum="b6639489e159b854b6dc43d5cb539043" FileSize="0,40029664"

These values can be obtained from
C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012Spring\SetupPrerequisites\VSTO 2010 Runtime\x86\vstor40_x86.exe

CheckSum is the MD5 checksum of the file.

This file is downloaded during the failed checksum error you got above.

Now you can delete the "VSTO 2010 Runtime" folder, click out of the redistributables page in InstallShield and back then download again. With the checksum now matching the error goes away.

Note that the redistributable may change to fix some security bug or something. This will change the MD5 and file size and require new matching values. To get the md5 hash, google some method. I ended up with something that adds a "checksum" page to file properties in windows explorer with various checksums so you can verify downloads: http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/

Comment: For reasons like this I suggest copying the PRQ and Folder to your Project Directory and redoing the references to use <ISProjectFolder> instead of <ISProductFolder>.  Otherwise you'll have trouble down the road when you install IS on a new machine or upgrade to a different version and they haven't fixed this.

Comment: Would that not hide updates / changes they make from you? Although I guess a diff will let you review what actually changed and reject the bad stuff again if you repeat the process when there is an update.

Comment: Yup, put it all in source control and use vendor branches to merge the changes in *AFTER* you approve them.